# Transferring iPhone Voice Memos

Tags: iphone, voice-memo

Is there a way of transferring iPhone voice memos to a Windows computer without linking it to the computer by iTunes or sending them via mail?
Thank you.

Comment: some apps allow to read ios disk directly from PC. Use it to transfer raw files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way to do is, is using an cloudsharing app, like Instashare (There are a bunch of them, just search the App store and you'll find a lot of them).

Concidering you'll use Instashare, download the app and set it up. Open your voice memo app and click on the share button. Your familiar share screen will popup. If it isn't listed yet, click on the more button next to Messages & Mail. Enable instashare or any app you want to use, close it by clicking done. Then click yours app its icon. Depending on the app, you have to choose where to place it, but after that it's stored for you. Just now download on you're pc and you're done.

For this method you'll need IOS 8, which is supported for the 4S. Otherwise it'll become really complicated to share it, then you'd better use mail or USB.